# proff of bounded integral

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ have a continuous derivative and $\int_{0} ^{1}f(x)dx=0$. Prove that $\forall \alpha \in (0,1)$

$$\left|\int_{0}^{\alpha}f(x)\, dx \right| \leq \frac{1}{8}  \max \left\{ |f^{\prime}(x)| \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1 \right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $F \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $F(x) := \int_{0}^{x}f(y)\, dy$
and $M := \max \left\{ |F^{\prime\prime}(x)| \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1 \right\}$
you have $F(0) = F(1) = 0$, and the claim is that
$\left| F(x) \right| \le \frac 18 M$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

For any $x \in [0, 1]$, Taylor's theorem gives
$$
0 = F(0) = F(x) + (- x) F'(x) + \frac 12 x^2 F''(u)
$$
and
$$
0 = F(1) = F(x) + (1 - x) F'(x) + \frac 12 (1-x)^2 F''(v)
$$
for some $u, v \in [0, 1]$. 
Now eliminate $F'(x)$ by
multiplying the first equation by $(1-x)$
and the second equation by $x$ and adding. This gives
$$
0 = F(x) + \frac 12 x^2 (1-x) F''(u) + \frac 12 x(1-x)^2 F''(v)
$$
and if follows that
$$
\left| F(x) \right| \le \frac 12 x^2 (1-x) M + \frac 12 x(1-x)^2 M
= \frac 12 x (1-x) M \le \frac 18 M
$$
since $x(1-x) \le 1/4$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

---

The example $F(x) = x(1-x)$ shows that the factor $1/8$ is best possible.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality (or else you can think about it like a worst case) we can say that $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[0, T]$ and $f(x) \leq 0$ on $[T, 1]$ (think why). Since $\int_0^1f(x)dx = 0$ then $\int_0^Tf(x)dx = -\int_T^1f(x)dx$ and ($M = \max\{|f'(x)|\}$)
$$
 \left|\int_0^Tf(x)dx\right| = \left|\int_0^T\int_T^xf'(y)dydx\right| \leq M \int_0^Txdx = M\frac{T^2}{2}
$$
For other integral we can get:
$$
 \left|\int_T^1f(x)dx\right| \leq M\frac{(1-T)^2}{2}
$$
Either $T$ or $(1-T)$ less or equal than $\frac{1}{2}$. And you can get that the whole integral:
$$
\left|\int_0^\alpha f(x)dx\right| \leq \int_0^T f(x)dx \leq M \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^2}{2} = \frac{M}{8}.
$$

Comment: Does your first equality assume that $f(0) = 0$? I am probably overlooking something ...

Comment: My fault, integrals should start from T since $f(T) = 0$.